# iMacros: Doesn't work try catch syntax in javascript

Tags: javascript, imacros

I write some iMacros script using js in **firefox**.
But i can't use try catch syntax.

```
    try {
        throw new Error("NotImplementedError message");
    } catch (ex1) {
        alert("ex1 instanceof Error = " + (ex1 instanceof Error));
        alert("ex1.name = " + ex1.name);
        alert("ex1.message = " + ex1.message);
    }

TypeError: ex1 is undefined, line 5
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgGrb.png)

Comment: Very strange because I ran this code on [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and it works as expected.

Comment: Could you please add some more context? What's your FF vesion, what version of iMacros, how exactly are you running the script? Are the alerts displayed when you run it?

Comment: It is correct js code. But it doesn't work in iMacros.
Ubuntu 16.04, FireFox 47.0, iMacros for Firefox 8.9.7

Added screenshot

Comment: I installed iMacros (version 8.9.7) on my Firefox (linux 64 bit, ver. 47.0) and I can reproduce your error now. [I tried a couple tricks](http://pastebin.com/xWDv1RGU) like defining a new function and passing ex1 as it's parameter or cloning the exception object, but it seems that it disappears right after you access it for the first time, which I agree is really odd.

Comment: After running your code the complete error I get is `TypeError: ex1 is undefined, line 5 (Error code: -991)`. Error code "-991" is "Javascript parsing/evaluation error" according to [this wiki page](http://wiki.imacros.net/Error_and_Return_Codes). I think you should submit a ticket [here](http://imacros.net/support/submit-a-ticket) and see what happens. If they reply, you could post their answer under this question. I think it might be a bug in their JS interpreter.

Comment: thanks @Jezor, I've written the ticket. I'll write a response.

Comment: I was thinking about it and first thing that came to my mind was that Error object might not have the fields that you are using, but if it was the case, a `ReferenceError` would be raised (according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3657237/5922757)). Anyway, you can replace all the alerts with only `var name = ex1.name` and the `TypeError` will still be present. We are only assigning here, not passing value to the function, so it should be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sent a report. They've approved it. But I don't know then they'll resolve it.

So I wrote temporary fix:

```js
    let Exception = {
        error: undefined,
        throw: function(error){
            this.error = error;
            throw error;
        },
    };
```

Using:

```
    try {
        Exception.throw(new Error('some text'));
    } catch(e) {
        e = Exception.error;
    //...
    }
```